# Ibatis Spring Stored Procedure with Multiple OUT

Tags: spring, ibatis

Is it possible to implement a stored procedure call in oracle, which has more than 3 output (OUT)
using Ibatis 2.3.4 integrated with Spring version 2.7,

If possible please provide link for reference,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I implemented oracle store procedure called using iBatis on Spring, and can't find the limitation about 3 OUT parameter as you described above. In my opinion, it's possible to create store procedure for your purpose, use this link as reference:

[Ibatis and Oracle Procedure](http://andrius.miasnikovas.lt/2008/09/ibatis-and-stored-oracle-proceduresfunctions/)

If you got any problem, please let me know.

HTH.